# Android: How Can I display all XML values of same tag name

Tags: java, android, xml, url, sax

I have the ff. XML from a URL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 
<Phonebook>
    <PhonebookEntry>
        <firstname>Michael</firstname> 
        <lastname>De Leon</lastname> 
        <Address>5, Cat Street</Address> 
    </PhonebookEntry>
    <PhonebookEntry>
        <firstname>John</firstname> 
        <lastname>Smith</lastname> 
        <Address>6, Dog Street</Address> 
    </PhonebookEntry>
</Phonebook>
```

I want to display both PhonebookEntry values (firstname,lastname,Address). Currently, my code displays only the PhonebookEntry of John Smith (the last entry). Here's my code.

**ParsingXML.java**

```
package com.example.parsingxml;

import java.net.Proxy;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class ParsingXML extends Activity {



    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
         super.onCreate(icicle);

         /* Create a new TextView to display the parsingresult later. */
         TextView tv = new TextView(this);
         try {
              /* Create a URL we want to load some xml-data from. */
              URL url = new URL("http://somedomain.com/jm/sampleXML.xml");
              URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
              /* Get a SAXParser from the SAXPArserFactory. */
              SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
              SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();

              /* Get the XMLReader of the SAXParser we created. */
              XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
              /* Create a new ContentHandler and apply it to the XML-Reader*/
              ExampleHandler myExampleHandler = new ExampleHandler();
              xr.setContentHandler(myExampleHandler);

              /* Parse the xml-data from our URL. */
              xr.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
              /* Parsing has finished. */

              /* Our ExampleHandler now provides the parsed data to us. */
              ParsedExampleDataSet parsedExampleDataSet =
                                            myExampleHandler.getParsedData();

              /* Set the result to be displayed in our GUI. */
              tv.setText(parsedExampleDataSet.toString());

         } catch (Exception e) {
              /* Display any Error to the GUI. */
              tv.setText("Error: " + e.getMessage());

         }
         /* Display the TextView. */
         this.setContentView(tv);
    }
}
```

**ExampleHandler.java**

```
package com.example.parsingxml;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;


public class ExampleHandler extends DefaultHandler{

     // ===========================================================
     // Fields
     // ===========================================================

     private boolean in_outertag = false;
     private boolean in_innertag = false;
     private boolean in_firstname = false;
     private boolean in_lastname= false;
     private boolean in_Address=false;


     private ParsedExampleDataSet myParsedExampleDataSet = new ParsedExampleDataSet();

     // ===========================================================
     // Getter & Setter
     // ===========================================================

     public ParsedExampleDataSet getParsedData() {
          return this.myParsedExampleDataSet;
     }

     // ===========================================================
     // Methods
     // ===========================================================
     @Override
     public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
          this.myParsedExampleDataSet = new ParsedExampleDataSet();
     }

     @Override
     public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
          // Nothing to do
     }

     /** Gets be called on opening tags like:
      * <tag>
      * Can provide attribute(s), when xml was like:
      * <tag attribute="attributeValue">*/
     @Override
     public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {

        if (localName.equals("PhoneBook")) {
            this.in_outertag = true;
        }else if (localName.equals("PhonebookEntry")) {
            this.in_innertag = true;
        }else if (localName.equals("firstname")) {
            this.in_firstname = true;
        }else if (localName.equals("lastname"))  {
            this.in_lastname= true;
        }else if(localName.equals("Address"))  {
            this.in_Address= true;
        } 

     }

     /** Gets be called on closing tags like:
      * </tag> */
     @Override
     public void endElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName)
               throws SAXException {
          if (localName.equals("Phonebook")) {
               this.in_outertag = false;
          }else if (localName.equals("PhonebookEntry")) {
               this.in_innertag = false;
          }else if (localName.equals("firstname")) {
               this.in_firstname = false;
          }else if (localName.equals("lastname"))  {
              this.in_lastname= false;
          }else if(localName.equals("Address"))  {
              this.in_Address= false;
          }
     }

     /** Gets be called on the following structure:
      * <tag>characters</tag> */
     @Override
    public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {
          if(this.in_firstname){
          myParsedExampleDataSet.setfirstname(new String(ch, start, length));
          }
          if(this.in_lastname){
          myParsedExampleDataSet.setlastname(new String(ch, start, length));
          }
          if(this.in_Address){
              myParsedExampleDataSet.setAddress(new String(ch, start, length));
          }
    }
}
```

**ParsedExampleDataSet.java**

```
package com.example.parsingxml;

public class ParsedExampleDataSet {
    private String firstname = null;
    private String lastname=null;
    private String Address=null;


    //Firstname
    public String getfirstname() {
         return firstname;
    }
    public void setfirstname(String firstname) {
         this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    //Lastname
    public String getlastname(){
        return lastname;
    }
    public void setlastname(String lastname){
        this.lastname=lastname;
    }

    //Address
    public String getAddress(){
        return Address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String Address){
        this.Address=Address;
    }

    public String toString(){
         return "Firstname: " + this.firstname + "\n" + "Lastname: " + this.lastname + "\n" + "Address: " + this.Address;

    }
}
```

I'm new to java and android dev, many thanks in advance for any help! :)

Comment: Just so you know there are better ways to deal with XML in Android. I would recommend not directly using all of the inbuilt parsers but to use Simple XML to do all the heavy lifting for you and you just directing the data with annotations: http://massaioli.homelinux.com/wordpress/2011/04/21/simple-xml-in-android-1-5-and-up/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other responses have already pointed out that you require a list to store all the `ParsedExampleDataSet` objects gotten from the XML.

But I want to point your attention to another thing about XML handlers which may bite you only later (and randomly). The characters method is not a good place to assign the values found between tags in you XML, because the characters method is not guaranteed to return all the characters in an element at once. It may be called multiple times within the same element to report characters found so far. With your implementation as it is right now, you will end up with missing data and wonder what is going on.

That said, what I would do it use a `StringBuilder` to accumulate your characters and then assign them in an `endElement(...)` call. Like so:

```
public class ExampleHandler extends DefaultHandler{

 // ===========================================================
 // Fields
 // ===========================================================

 private StringBuilder mStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

 private ParsedExampleDataSet mParsedExampleDataSet = new ParsedExampleDataSet();
 private List<ParsedExampleDataSet> mParsedDataSetList = new ArrayList<ParsedExampleDataSet>();

 // ===========================================================
 // Getter & Setter
 // ===========================================================

 public List<ParsedExampleDataSet> getParsedData() {
      return this.mParsedDataSetList;
 }

 // ===========================================================
 // Methods
 // ===========================================================

 /** Gets be called on opening tags like:
  * <tag>
  * Can provide attribute(s), when xml was like:
  * <tag attribute="attributeValue">*/
 @Override
 public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
    if (localName.equals("PhonebookEntry")) {
        this.mParsedExampleDataSet = new ParsedExampleDataSet();
    }

 }

 /** Gets be called on closing tags like:
  * </tag> */
 @Override
 public void endElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName)
           throws SAXException {
      if (localName.equals("PhonebookEntry")) {
           this.mParsedDataSetList.add(mParsedExampleDataSet);
      }else if (localName.equals("firstname")) {
           mParsedExampleDataSet.setfirstname(mStringBuilder.toString().trim());
      }else if (localName.equals("lastname"))  {
          mParsedExampleDataSet.setlastname(mStringBuilder.toString().trim());
      }else if(localName.equals("Address"))  {
          mParsedExampleDataSet.setAddress(mStringBuilder.toString().trim());
      }
      mStringBuilder.setLength(0);
 }

 /** Gets be called on the following structure:
  * <tag>characters</tag> */
 @Override
public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {
      mStringBuilder.append(ch, start, length);
}
}
```

You can then retrieve the list of ParsedExampleDataSets in your activity and either display in multiple text views or only in one. Your `Activity.onCreate(...)` method may look like:

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
         super.onCreate(icicle);

         /* Create a new TextView to display the parsingresult later. */
         TextView tv = new TextView(this);
         try {
              /* Create a URL we want to load some xml-data from. */
              URL url = new URL("http://somedomain.com/jm/sampleXML.xml");
              URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();

              /* Create a new ContentHandler and apply it to the XML-Reader*/
              ExampleHandler myExampleHandler = new ExampleHandler();

              //remember to import android.util.Xml
              Xml.parse(url.openStream(), Xml.Encoding.UTF_8, myExampleHandler);


              /* Our ExampleHandler now provides the parsed data to us. */
              List<ParsedExampleDataSet> parsedExampleDataSetList =
                                            myExampleHandler.getParsedData();

              /* Set the result to be displayed in our GUI. */
              for(ParsedExampleDataSet parsedExampleDataSet : parsedExampleDataSetList){
                  tv.append(parsedExampleDataSet.toString());
              }

         } catch (Exception e) {
              /* Display any Error to the GUI. */
              tv.setText("Error: " + e.getMessage());

         }
         /* Display the TextView. */
         this.setContentView(tv);
    }
```

Comment: Wow! thank you so much for your code and advice, but I didn't use your second code block, I still used my ParsingXML.java above and changed the line: **ParsedExampleDataSet parsedExampleDataSet = myExampleHandler.getParsedData();** to **List<ParsedExampleDataSet> parsedExampleDataSet = myExampleHandler.getParsedData();** ... thanks also to others who responded! :)

Answer (score 0):

You only have one ParsedExampleDataSet object in your handler, so there's only room to store one entry. Change ExampleHandler to have an `ArrayList<ParsedExampleDataSet> results` and also a `ParsedExampleDataSet currentSet`. Inside `startElement`, when you see the `PhoneBook` tag, set `currentSet` to a new instance of `ParsedExampleDataSet` and add it to `results`. After parsing, `results` should contain everything you want.

Answer (score 0):

You were close. Since you have many `PhoneBookeEntrys` you need to store them somewhere:

```
public class ExampleHandler extends DefaultHandler{

 // ===========================================================
 // Fields
 // ===========================================================

 private boolean in_outertag = false;
 private boolean in_innertag = false;
 private boolean in_firstname = false;
 private boolean in_lastname= false;
 private boolean in_Address=false;

 private ParsedExampleDataSet myParsedExampleDataSet = new ParsedExampleDataSet();
 private List<ParsedExampleDataSet> allSets = new ArrayList<ParsedExampleDataSet>();

 // ===========================================================
 // Getter & Setter
 // ===========================================================

 public ParsedExampleDataSet getParsedData() {
      return this.myParsedExampleDataSet;
 }

 // ===========================================================
 // Methods
 // ===========================================================

 /** Gets be called on opening tags like:
  * <tag>
  * Can provide attribute(s), when xml was like:
  * <tag attribute="attributeValue">*/
 @Override
 public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {

    if (localName.equals("PhoneBook")) {
        this.in_outertag = true;
    }else if (localName.equals("PhonebookEntry")) {
        this.in_innertag = true;
        this.myParsedExampleDataSet = new ParsedExampleDataSet();
    }else if (localName.equals("firstname")) {
        this.in_firstname = true;
    }else if (localName.equals("lastname"))  {
        this.in_lastname= true;
    }else if(localName.equals("Address"))  {
        this.in_Address= true;
    } 

 }

 /** Gets be called on closing tags like:
  * </tag> */
 @Override
 public void endElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName)
           throws SAXException {
      if (localName.equals("Phonebook")) {
           this.in_outertag = false;
      }else if (localName.equals("PhonebookEntry")) {
           this.in_innertag = false;
           allSets.add(myParsedExampleDataSet);
      }else if (localName.equals("firstname")) {
           this.in_firstname = false;
      }else if (localName.equals("lastname"))  {
          this.in_lastname= false;
      }else if(localName.equals("Address"))  {
          this.in_Address= false;
      }
 }

 /** Gets be called on the following structure:
  * <tag>characters</tag> */
 @Override
public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {
      if(this.in_firstname){
      myParsedExampleDataSet.setfirstname(new String(ch, start, length));
      }
      if(this.in_lastname){
      myParsedExampleDataSet.setlastname(new String(ch, start, length));
      }
      if(this.in_Address){
          myParsedExampleDataSet.setAddress(new String(ch, start, length));
      }
}
}
```

Comment: You just added this line right? private List<ParsedExampleDataSet> allSets = new ArrayList<ParsedExampleDataSet>(); ... how can i retrieve all the values then, sorry for this noob question...

Comment: Sorry small mistake: make it public.

Answer (score 0):

I found an XML tutorial online [here](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/javax.xml.parsers/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java.html) and editied it to work with your XML file. Below is the code. For the sake of testing it on my machine, I've sourced the XML file from a local file rather than online, but it shouldn't be too hard to work out.

This should hopefully point you in the right direction.

```
package phonebook;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import java.io.File;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;


public class program {
    public static void main(String argv[]) {

          try {
              File file = new File("phonebook.xml");
              DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
              DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
              Document doc = db.parse(file);
              doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
              System.out.println("Root element " + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
              NodeList nodeLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("PhonebookEntry");
              System.out.println("Information of all entries");

              for (int s = 0; s < nodeLst.getLength(); s++) {

                Node fstNode = nodeLst.item(s);

                if (fstNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
                {
                  Element fstElmnt = (Element) fstNode;

                  // Firstname
                  NodeList fstNmElmntLst = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("firstname");
                  Element fstNmElmnt = (Element) fstNmElmntLst.item(0);
                  NodeList fstNm = fstNmElmnt.getChildNodes();
                  System.out.println("First Name : "  + ((Node) fstNm.item(0)).getNodeValue());

                  // Lastname
                  NodeList lstNmElmntLst = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("lastname");
                  Element lstNmElmnt = (Element) lstNmElmntLst.item(0);
                  NodeList lstNm = lstNmElmnt.getChildNodes();
                  System.out.println("Last Name : " + ((Node) lstNm.item(0)).getNodeValue());

                  // Address
                  NodeList addrNmElmntLst = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("Address");
                  Element addrNmElmnt = (Element) addrNmElmntLst.item(0);
                  NodeList addrNm = addrNmElmnt.getChildNodes();
                  System.out.println("Address : " + ((Node) addrNm.item(0)).getNodeValue());
                }
              }
          } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
         }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I'm getting a force close message, I have my code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866113/android-dom-parsing-gets-force-close-message